# Inner product on Fock spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, mathematical-physics

I'm trying to understand Fock spaces by myself and so I got some very basic doubts I'd like to clarify with you. Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a Hilbert space and $\mathcal{F}(\mathcal{H}):= \bigoplus_{n=0}^{\infty}\mathcal{H}^{\otimes n}$ its associated Fock space. Here, $\mathcal{H}^{\otimes n}$ is the $n$-fold tensor product $\mathcal{H}^{\otimes n} := \mathcal{H}\otimes \cdots \otimes \mathcal{H}$. Now, I'm most interested in bosonic/fermionic Fock spaces. Let $\wedge^{n}\mathcal{H}$ to be the subspace of all antisymmetric tensors of $\mathcal{H}^{\otimes n}$. Then, the fermionic Fock space is $\mathcal{F}_{f}(\mathcal{H}) := \bigoplus_{n=0}^{\infty}\wedge^{n}\mathcal{H}$. If all these being said, let me ask:

**(1)** As far as I understand, the direct sum $\bigoplus_{n=0}^{\infty}\mathcal{H}^{\otimes n}$ simply means the space of all sequences $(x_{0},x_{1},...)$ with all but finitely many nonzero entries, with $x_{n}\in \mathcal{H}^{\otimes n}$. Thus, it seems natural to define an inner product $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ on $\mathcal{F}(\mathcal{H})$ by setting:
$$\langle x, y \rangle := \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\langle x_{n},y_{n}\rangle_{\mathcal{H}^{\otimes n}}$$
With this inner product, I believe $\mathcal{F}(\mathcal{H})$ becomes a Hilbert space. Is this reasoning correct?

**(2)** Related to the above question, some texts I know actually define the same notion of inner product I defined above but directly for fermionic and bosonic Fock spaces. This sounds okay to me as well, but it seems more natural to me to define the inner product on $\mathcal{F}_{f}(\mathcal{H})$ and then restric it to each subspace. Are these constructions equivalent?

**(3)** Some texts define the Fock space as the space of all sequences $x = (x_{0},x_{1},...)$ with $x_{n} \in \mathcal{H}^{\otimes n}$ satisfying $||x||^{2} := \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}||x_{n}||^{2}_{\mathcal{H}^{\otimes n}} < +\infty$. If the reasoning of my first question is correct, it seems that this definition is just a consequence of my inner product on $\mathcal{F}(\mathcal{H})$, right?

Comment: If you insist that your sequences $(x_0,x_1,\ldots)$ have only finitely many nonzero terms, then they won't form a complete space

Comment: @AnginaSeng but isn't it the definition of direct sum of vector spaces?

Comment: If you want completeness, you need a construction like (3)

Comment: Let $J$ be an index set and $H_j$ a Hilbert space for every $j\in J$. Then the Hilbert space direct sum $\bigoplus_{j\in J}H_j$ is defined as the subset of $\prod_{j\in J}H_j$ for which $\sum_j \|v_j\|_{H_j}^2<\infty$. The inner product is given by $\langle v,w\rangle:=\sum_{j\in J}\langle v_j,w_j\rangle_{H_j}$. Note a sum over an uncountable index set can only converge if at most countably many terms are non-zero, so every $v$ is "countably supported" in the $H_j$, even if $J$ is very very big.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in one of the comments, you need a construction as in $(3)$ for your space to be complete whereas your construction in $(1)$ is not necessarily complete, so they are not equivalent. However, if you take the Hilbert space completion of the space you defined in (1), this space will be the same as the space defined in (3).

See the discussion here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_sum_of_modules#Direct_sum_of_Hilbert_spaces.
See also
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fock_space#Definition, the fourth paragraph.